# How to create a sha256 from a string using crypto

Tags: node.js, expo

So I am trying to create a nonce following this code example

```
   let randomString = uuid();

  // create a sha256 of randomString, this will be the nonce sent to apple during authentication
  const nonce = await Crypto.digestStringAsync(
    Crypto.CryptoDigestAlgorithm.SHA256,
    randomString
  );
```

However this example is for expo's version of "Crypto" and I am using the Crypto built into node.js and tried doing this

```
    let randomString = uuid(); // <--- this just creates a random string for me

   const nonce = await crypto
      .createHmac('sha256', randomString)
      .update(uuid())
      .digest('string');
```

But this does not seem to create the nonce in the format I need. Does anyone who knows expo's crypto and the crypto built into node.js know what I am doing wrong? I am pretty sure I am just not using the nodejs crypto the same way as the expo crypto example so maybe someone who knows them both can tell me what the nodejs crypto version of that expo crypto example would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expo default format of digest string is hex ([doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/crypto/#api))

> options   `CryptoDigestOptions`   Format of the digest string. Defaults to: `CryptoDigestOptions.HEX`

So you just have to change `.digest("string")` to `.digest("hex")`

```
let randomString = uuid()

const nonce = await crypto
  .createHmac("sha256", randomString)
  .update(uuid())
  .digest("hex")
```